# wrong printing 2D char array

Tags: c++

I am doing my homework and I declared a 2D array but it's not printing what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char NOTE[7][3] = { {'D','O'} , {'R','E'} , {'M','I'} , {'F','A'} , {'S','O','L'} , {'L','A'} , {'S','I'} };

    for (int i = 0; i <7 ; i++)
        cout <<setw(10)<< NOTE[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I want to get:

```
DO
RE
MI
FA
SOL
LA
SI
DO
```

but I got:

```
DO
RE
MI
FA
SOLLA
LA
SI
DO
```

Comment: Hint: it's a 2D array.. think 2 loops.

Comment: `i < ` looks suspicious

Comment: 'S','O','L' plus the '\0' terminator doesn't fit in a `char[3]` so your string isn't a valid C-style string.

Comment: It's not your real code `i < ;` does not compile. Fix it please.

Comment: thank you i forgot about the  '\0' terminator !

Comment: i am new to this comunity community, you guys are awesome thank you :))

Comment: There is a simple way how to fix the output, but when the homework is working with 2D arrays, this fix is a no go. You should make a second for *(`for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)`)* and print a single character in this cycle. Do not forget to write only correct characters and do not print the not used character.

Answer (score 2):

`NOTE[i]` is an array of characters. `<< NOTE[i]` inserts this array into a character stream. The array argument decays to a pointer to the first character.

The documentation says that behaviour is undefined unless the pointer operand points to a null terminated array. The array `{'S','O','L'}` is not null terminated. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined  <sub>- although it could be argued that the behaviour of iterating across boundaries subarrays of a multidimensional array should be well defined (with the behaviour shown in your program), but strict interpretation of the standard is that doing so is UB.</sub>

So, to get the output you want, you either need to 1. null terminate each sub array (and therefore need a larger array), or to 2. print each character individually.

Comment: @MaxLanghof the array has plenty of null terminators. The length of each subarray is 3. `{'D','O'}` initialises the first two characters explicitly and the third one is implicitly value initialised. A character value initialised is the null terminator.